# how to add file to the specified embedded JAR resource

Tags: java

I am using some API in which there is a class Reader which have a method readXml(String path)

now when i use this method and give some path which in my computer like

```
           Reader reader = new Reader();
           reader.readXml("C:\\work\\myfile.xml");
```

it always faile to read the file

In there API documentation it is mentioned

```
      readXml(java.lang.String resourcePath) 
      Loads the orthography model, from the specified embedded JAR resource.
```

so do i need to put my file in some embedded jar resources ,if yes what would be the way of doing it and then reading from it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording is a bit strange, but I think that what the documentation means is that the resource path is a path used by the classloader to load a resource. The file is thus not searched in the file system, but in the classpath, following the rules detailed in [ClassLoader.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

So, the XML file should be accessible from the classpath. Suppose `c:\work` is in the classpath, the resource path should thus be `"myfile.xml"` or `"/myfile.xml"` depending on how this method is implemented. If `c:\` is in the classpath, then the path should be `"work/myfile.xml"` or `"/work/myfile.xml"`.

If this library is a general-purpose API and is well-designed, it should accept something other than a resource path as argument, like a java.io.Reader or java.io.InputStream.

Comment: thanks , tried but didnt work , there's another file which is getting read by this command correctly, but this file in with some JarFile , can i make some jar file myself and then add this file within my jarfile ? how can i make my own jar file